# Adding new rows with default value based on dataframe values into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data with a large number of columns:

```
df:
ID   col1   col2   col3 ... col100
1    a      x      0        1  
1    a      x      1        1
2    a      y      1        1
4    a      z      1        0  
...
98   a      z      1        1
100  a      x      1        0
```

I want to fill in the missing `ID` values with a default value that indicate that the data is missing here. For example here it would be `ID` `3` and hypothetically speaking lets say the missing row data looks like `ID` `100`

```
ID   col1   col2  col3 ... col100
3    a      x     1        0
99   a      x     1        0
```

Expected output:

```
df:
ID   col1   col2   col3 ... col100
1    a      x      0        1  
1    a      x      1        1
2    a      y      1        1
3    a      x      1        0
4    a      z      1        0  
...
98   a      z      1        1
99   a      x     1        0
100  a      x      1        0
```

I'm also ok with the 3 and 99 being at the bottom.

I have tried several ways of appending new rows:

```
noresponse = df[filterfornoresponse].head(1).copy() #assume that this will net us row 100

for i in range (1, maxID):
    if len(df[df['ID'] == i) == 0: #IDs with no rows ie missing data
        temp = noresponse.copy()
        temp['ID'] = i
        df.append(temp, ignore_index = True)
```

This method doesn't seem to append anything.

I have also tried

```
pd.concat([df, temp], ignore_index = True)
```

instead of `df.append`

I have also tried adding the rows to a list `noresponserows` with the intention of concating the list with `df`:

```
noresponserows = []

for i in range (1, maxID):
    if len(df[df['ID'] == i) == 0: #IDs with no rows ie missing data
        temp = noresponse.copy()
        temp['ID'] = i
        noresponserows.append(temp)
```

But here the list always ends up with only 1 row when in my data I know there are more than one rows that need to be appended.

I'm not sure why I am having trouble appending more than once instance of `noresponse` into the list, and why I can't directly append to a dataframe. I feel like I am missing something here.

I think it might have to do with me taking a copy of a row in the `df` vs constructing a new one. The reason why I take a copy of a row to get `noresponse` is because there are a large amount of columns so it is easier to just take an existing row.

Comment: What do you mean by "missing ID value"?

Comment: You need to do `df.append(..., inplace=True)` or `df = df.append(...)` because `df.append()` returns a new dataframe by default.

Comment: Will you please provide a sample dataframe containing your expected output?

Comment: added expected output @richardec, what I mean is that I want to have Ids span all contiguous values from 1 to 100 so here 3 and 99 are missing and I want to add them

Comment: See my answer, @SemicolonExpected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have a dataframe like this:

```
>>> df
  col1 col2  col100  ID
0    a    x       0   1
1    a    y       3   2
2    a    z       1   4
```

First, set the `ID` column to be the index:

```
>>> df = df.set_index('ID')
>>> df
   col1 col2  col100
ID                  
1     a    x       0
2     a    y       3
4     a    z       1
```

Now you can use `df.loc` to easily add rows.

Let's select the last row as the default row:

```
>>> default_row = df.iloc[-1]
>>> default_row
col1      a
col2      z
col100    1
Name: 4, dtype: object
```

We can add it right into the dataframe at ID 3:

```
>>> df.loc[3] = default_row
>>> df
   col1 col2  col100
ID                  
1     a    x       0
2     a    y       3
4     a    z       1
3     a    z       1
```

Then use [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) to sort the rows lexicographically by index:

```
>>> df = df.sort_index()
>>> df
   col1 col2  col100
ID                  
1     a    x       0
2     a    y       3
3     a    z       1
4     a    z       1
```

And, optionally, reset the index:

```
>>> df = df.reset_index()
>>> df
   ID col1 col2  col100
0   1    a    x       0
1   2    a    y       3
2   3    a    z       1
3   4    a    z       1
```

Comment: I dont think I can use ID as an index because I have duplicate values, in fact it is expected that there are multiple instances of each "ID". For example in my example I have two instances of 1

Comment: Yes, you can use the index in that case. It's totally valid for the index to have multiple values. I know it's counter-intuitive, but it's the same thing for columns.